# "ping.c:13:34: error: too many arguments to function call, expected single argument '__command', have 5 arguments"

Tags: c, cs50, c99

So im new to c99 so this error is probably incredibly simple but, I'm trying to ping someone through a c script but I cant figure out how to fix this error! I tried everything and this is just about the closest I've gotten.

This is the code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
  
int main() 
{ 
    char name = get_char("target: ");
    char test = get_char("target: ");
    char er = get_char("target: ");
    char tr = get_char("target: ");
    printf("%c.%c.%c.%c\n", name, test, er, tr);
    system("ping %c.%c.%c.%c\n", name, test, er, tr);
    
   return 0; 
}
```

This is the error I get when compiling:

```
**ping.c:13:34: error: too many arguments to function call, expected single argument '__command', have 5 arguments
    system("ping %c.%c.%c.%c\n", name, test, er, tr);
    ~~~~~~                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdlib.h:781:1: note: 'system' declared here
extern int system (const char *__command) __wur;
1 error generated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'ping' failed
make: *** [ping] Error 1**
```

Comment: You'll need to construct the string you wish to pass to `system`. Try `sprintf`.

Comment: Also, you probably want the IP address to consist of integers in decimal or hex format, rather than characters.

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow! The error message told you *exactly* what the problem was. [system()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) only takes *one* argument, not the five you gave. Please look up the functions you are using before using them, or at the very least when the compiler complains about them.

Comment: Note that using string concatenation to build a string you pass to `system()` is a common source of severe security bugs. You __really__ shouldn't do it.

Comment: Consider using `posix_spawn` instead of `system()`; you can directly pass it an argv list to be passed to ping, so there's no shell interpreting a string (whereby you need to worry about one of the arguments being `$(rm -rf ~)` or other content that an attacker could reasonably expect to use to take control of your system).

Answer (score 0):

Although the standard C function `printf()` is defined to take multiple arguments, `system()` is not. `system()` takes a pre-formatted character array (string). There's no reason *in principle* for `system()` not to take multiple arguments -- it was just not implemented that way.

You can construct a string argument to `system()` using, `sprintf()` or, more robustly, `snprintf()`. With `gcc` it might be more elegant (but not portable) to use the `asprintf()` function, which will automatically allocate a string in memory (which you must later free).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use more than one argument in `system()` function, it solely accepts one. It is not like `printf("%c %c", a, b)`. Another problem is that, you need to obtain either `char` pointer type or array, since the IP is not guaranteed to be only formatted straightforwardly `x.x.x.x`, it might be `xx.xxx.x.xx` too – as an instance.

As mentioned in the comments, you should consider taking the help of `sprintf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 50

int get_string(void) {
  int val = 0;

  printf("Enter a target: ");

  if (scanf("%d", &val) == 0)
    return 0;
  return val;
}

int main(void) {
  // Initializing the strings
  int x1 = get_int();
  int x2 = get_int();
  int x3 = get_int();
  int x4 = get_int();

  char buffer[MAX] = {0};

  // buffer = ping str1.str2.str3.str4
  sprintf(buffer, "ping %d.%d.%d.%d", x1, x2, x3, x4);

  // Command execution will succeed now, only one argument given here
  system(buffer);

  return 0;
}
```

---

**As a test case:**

```
Enter target: 127
Enter target: 0
Enter target: 0
Enter target: 1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Comment: ..."should use" is a bit strong, insofar as concatenating strings into a buffer passed to a shell is a fast route to shell injection bugs. If the OP's code were at least accepting integers rather than strings as the argument, that could be a little less risky.

Comment: `Enter target: $(touch /tmp/gotcha; echo 1)` as an example... and then check `/tmp`. Obvs., in real life that could be code that sets up a reverse shell, exfiltrates private data, installs a rootkit...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, good point. Edited and thanks. This edited method seems more reliable.